# layout is different while using ng-repeat - array in object

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I have a user object which has different attributes such as name, email etc. Along with that, it also contains an array which specifies the user roles. My problem is when I iterate over that array, if it has only one value, it gives me some alignment problem. If it has more than one, the layout is fine. Find the screenshot below to get clear idea. Can someone help me? TIA

Example of user data -users = [
    {accountId: 1, name: "xyz", email: "xyz@xyz.com", role: ["Super","Regular"]},
    {accountId: 2, name: "single role as string", email: "xyz@xyz.com", role: "Super"}];

[image]

Here's my code

```
   <table class="table table-inverse">
    <thead>
     <th>User Id</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Role</th>
    </thead>
    </table>  
   <table class="table table-inverse">
        <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="user in users ">
            <td width="10%"><span>{{user.accountId}}</span></td>
            <td width="12%" ><span>{{user.name}}</span></td>
            <td width="14%"><span>{{user.email}}</span></td>
            <td width="12%"><span ng-repeat="role in user.role ">
                {{role}}
            </span></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is shown is not enough to sort out any *"alignment problem"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your data I can't be sure but it looks like the roles for those users is a string instead of an array such as this.

`{accountId: 2, name: "single role as string", email: "xyz@xyz.com", role: "Super"}`

This ng-repeat `<span ng-repeat="role in user.role ">}}</span>` when used on a string is creating a `<span>` for every letter which is why it is spaced like that.

I suggest changing it to always be an array of roles.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("controller", function($scope) {

  $scope.users = [
    {accountId: 1, name: "multiple roles as array", email: "xyz@xyz.com", role: ["Super","Regular"]},
    {accountId: 2, name: "single role as string", email: "xyz@xyz.com", role: "Super"},
    {accountId: 3, name: "single role as array", email: "xyz@xyz.com", role: ["Super"]},
  ];
  
  // Change user roles to arrays if string
  angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user) {
    if (typeof user.role === "string") {
      user.role = [user.role];
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <table class="table table-inverse">
    <thead>
      <th>User Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Role</th>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-inverse">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users ">
        <td width="10%"><span>{{user.accountId}}</span></td>
        <td width="12%"><span>{{user.name}}</span></td>
        <td width="14%"><span>{{user.email}}</span></td>
        <td width="12%"><span ng-repeat="role in user.role ">
                {{role}}
            </span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are right. So what I should I do to fix it if I am getting the String?
I cannot change the backend

Comment: Once you get the data from the backend you can change it however you want. Iterate over your array of users and if the role is a string change it to an array. I've added an example to the snippet.